# Spring @ComponentScan for @Service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

I have a package named `com.example.service`, and in my Spring Configuration class I have the annotation `@ComponentScan({"com.example.service"},{"com.example.controller"})`.

When I try to `@Autowire` a service, code compilation fails with a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`. The MyService interface is annotated with `@Service`.

Currently I use a quite ugly workaround and declare every single service bean in my ExampleConfig.java like

```
@Bean
public MyService myService() {
    return new MyServiceImpl();
}
```

Generally the `@ComponentScan` seems to work, if I remove the controller package, the controllers are not found. What did I understand wrong? Please let me know, if I missed out any relevant information.

Comment: An exception doesn't happen at compile-time. Keep the error types separate, or you'll be looking for solutions in the wrong places.

Comment: You are absolutely right with this. In this point I was inexact with my description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > The MyService interface is annotated with @Service

You must annotate the implementation of your interface. Not the interface itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code for `ComponentScan` annotation for scanning multiple packages:

```
@ComponentScan({"com.example.service","com.example.controller"})
```

instead of

```
@ComponentScan({"com.example.service"},{"com.example.controller"})
```

[@ComponentScan](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) uses string array for scanning multiple base packages.

Comment: I am sorry, but I guess you did not read the question properly. This is exactly what I am doing. But Jens did provide the correct answer.